# Installshield write to 64-bit registry

Tags: 32bit-64bit, installshield

I'm building an installer that automatically selects which software to install based on the architecture (VersionNT64 condition on one feature, NOT VersionNT64 on the other), but there are a couple of registry keys that need to go in as well. If I turn on "64-Bit Component", it will (apparently) write to the appropriate part of the registry, but that requires a flag in the installer info that prevents it from opening on a 32-bit machine. The component even has the VersionNT64 condition on it, so it wouldn't even be used on a 32-bit machine, so is there another way around this? I have a couple of alternatives in mind (reset the flag after compile; custom action on a .reg file) but I'd prefer something more streamlined.

Comment: If you're distributing as a .exe file, we suggest using a Suite project (include one .msi for each architecture and condition appropriately). However if you're distributing as a .msi file, this won't help.

Comment: Basically I want the user to double-click on a single file (preferably MSI, but apparently it'll have to be EXE) and have the installer decide which components to use and where to put them. So the question becomes how do I do that? I don't see Suite Project in the menus.

Comment: Oh, I get it, it's in Premium. Looks like I'll have to make two projects and an EXE of my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know you can a component marked as a 64-bit one in a 32 bit package without preventing the package to work on x86 machines. Only if the package type is set to x64 it will stop working on x86 machines.

Comment: My understanding is that such x64 components in an x86 package will not be installed to their 64-bit location. So while it won't prevent installation, it won't have the desired effect. For that reason, InstallShield prevents this combination from being built.

Comment: From what I know the redirection to Program Files (x86) or Wow6432Node is controlled by the OS, based on the package type, and for x86 packages all resources are included in these locations. However, after a small test I can see that for registry entries, setting the 64 bit flag on the component disables the redirection,

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in testing, while it did select the right Program Files folder, and the right binary set, and showed everything else right, it still got redirected to (x86) in the end.